# transformar variável js em objeto json

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenha a variável abaixo:

```
[object Object]
  '0%' : [{ 'margin-left':'-0%'}],
  '25%' : [{ 'margin-left':'-0%'}],
  '30%' : [{ 'margin-left':'-100%'}],
  '50%' : [{ 'margin-left':'-100%'}],
  '55%' : [{ 'margin-left':'-200%'}],
  '75%' : [{ 'margin-left':'-200%'}],
  '80%' : [{ 'margin-left':'-300%'}],
  '100%' : [{ 'margin-left':'-300%'}],
```

Trazido por

```
console.log(imagem);
```

Como fazer para transformá-la em um objeto json?

De onde vem isso?

```
  var tempoTransicao = 5;
  var quantasImagens = $("div.slider ul.slide li img").size();
  var tamanhoIntervalos = Math.round(100/quantasImagens);
  var tempoImagens = 0;
  var t = 0;    
  var imagem = "";  
  var imagens = {};

  for (i = 0; i < quantasImagens; i++) {    

      tMin = t + tempoTransicao;
      tMax = t + tamanhoIntervalos; 
      t+=tamanhoIntervalos;

      if(i==0) tMin=0;
      if(i==quantasImagens) tMax=100;         

      imagem += "'" + tMin + "%' : [{ 'margin-left':'-" + tempoImagens + "%'}],";
      imagem += "'" + tMax + "%' : [{ 'margin-left':'-" + tempoImagens + "%'}],";

      tempoImagens+=100;

  }

  $.keyframe.define([
        $.extend(
          { name: 'tocaSlide' }, 
          imagemjson
          )
  ]);
```

Algum erro nessa construção?

```
var jsonString = "{ \"0%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-0%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"25%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-0%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"30%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-100%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"50%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-100%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"55%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-200%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"75%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-200%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"80%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-300%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"100%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-300%\"}}";

    jsonString = JSON.parse(jsonString);

console.log(jsonString);

$.keyframe.define([
      $.extend(
        { name: 'jsonString' }, 
           jsonString
        )
]);
```

Comment: Podes mostrar de onde vem essa string? Assim como está isso tem um erro de sintaxe pois o JavaScript não permite quebras de linha dentro de strings...

Comment: sim, no final da pergunta. o objetivo é gerar o obj json na variável imagem.

Comment: Agora fiquei ainda mais curioso: que aplicação é essa? ou melhor: qual é a funcionalidade que queres criar?

Comment: então, eu quero usar a função    $.keyframe.define([, e colocar essa variável json dentro como está no fim da pergunta. O objetivo é alterar dinamicamente um keyframe css

Answer (score 1):

Basta usares a função **[parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** exemplo:

```
var jsonString = "{ \"0\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-0%\"} }";
jsonString = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: deu erro na posição 0

Comment: Resposta editada, precisas escapar as aspas

Comment: Então, com uma só linha deu certo, mas eu adicionei no final do pergunta o json complelo e não está dando certo. Será que errei na construção?

Comment: no teu caso acho que era melhor construíres um objecto em javascript e converter para json, simples